# getting different response when send post request from web and from desktop to https

Tags: java, apache, https

I am sending post request to a secure website. When i do it from web like

```
<body>
    <form method=POST action= "https://www.abc.com" >
        <textarea name="Request" rows="30%" cols="80%"></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="Submit"> 
    </form>    
</body>
```

What i do, i paste the xml in the textares and submit the form and get the response. Fine. Now when i try to do the same thing from plain java, then i get the certificate issue

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target
```

If i bypass the ssl, the i get the responce with `systemError`. Why ?

Here what i am doing

```
@Override
public HttpsURLConnection getHttpsConnection() throws Exception {   
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted( final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType ) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted( final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType ) {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

            }       
    } ;

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

    sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {

        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {              
            return true;          
        }           
    };

    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);

    try {   
        URL myUrl = new URL(this.url);
        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();    
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        throw new Exception("Error in getting connecting to url: " + url + " :: " + e.getMessage());

    }

    return urlConnection;

} //end of getHttpsConnection()

private void processHttpRequest(HttpsURLConnection connection, String method, Map<String, String> params) throws Exception {

    StringBuffer requestParams = new StringBuffer();

    if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
           Iterator<String> paramIterator = params.keySet().iterator();
           while (paramIterator.hasNext()) {
               String key = paramIterator.next();
               String value = params.get(key);
               requestParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
               requestParams.append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
               requestParams.append("&");

           }
    }

    try {

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        if ("POST".equals(method)) {    
            // set request method to POST
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

        } else {
            // set request method to GET
            connection.setDoOutput(false);

        }

        String parameters = requestParams.toString();

        if ("POST".equals(method) && params != null && params.size() > 0) {

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(os);
            wr.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(parameters, "UTF-8"));
            wr.writeBytes(parameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            /**
             * 

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(requestParams.toString());
            writer.flush();  
            writer.close();
           */
        }

     // reads response, store line by line in an array of Strings
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

      List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

      String line = "";
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          response.add(line);
      }

      reader.close();

      String[] myResponse = (String[]) response.toArray(new String[0]);

      if (myResponse != null && myResponse.length > 0) {
          System.out.println("RESPONSE FROM: " + this.url);
          for (String myLine : response) {
              System.out.println(myLine);
          }
      }  
    } catch(Exception e) {  
        throw new Exception("Error in sending Post :: " + e.getMessage());

    }   
}
```

Here how i am calling it

```
String req = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
    req = req + "<abc>";
     req = req + "   
     ....   
       req = req + " </xyz>";
    req = req + "</abc>";

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

buffer.append(req);

HttpServices httpServices = context.getBean("httpService", HttpServices.class);

String method = "POST";
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("request", buffer.toString());

try {

    HttpsURLConnection connection = httpServices.getHttpsConnection();
    httpServices.processHttpRequest(connection, method, params);

} catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}
```

i get response something like this. Ofcourse i can not show the exact responce. But it looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
    <SystemError>
        <Message>87b24972</Message>
    </SystemError>
</Result>
```

Why i am getting different response from plain java? I also tried the same thing with the Apache http client, by pass the SSL, but from Apache client i am getting the same response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The body of your post must lok like

```
Request=<?xml ...
```

You forgot the name of the request parameter in your `POST`.

Also for your `ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed` you need at least the root certificate of your communication partner. It looks like the default certificates of Java do not include the root certificate needed.

Comment: I tried `String req = "Request=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";...` but the response is same, i.e., error ... What is root certificate? You mean root certificate from the hhtps site which i am trying to connect ? by passing SSL is not enough to get the response ?

Comment: @Basit Bypassing SSL means not using SSL at all. Also I suggest using a web browser with developer tools to see what exactly is sent to the server.

Comment: @ Uwe Plonus how can i check from web browser, i am sending request from plain java ?

Comment: @Basit you wrote that you have done this with a web form. This web form can be opened in a browser and with developer tools you can track the network traffic.

Comment: yes but web is working fine. I want to do it with non-web. I have a certificate from the https site from which i am trying to connect. Can i use it to overcome `PKIX path building failed:`. I have a file root.cer. I have a JDK in my class path. There is JRE with in the JDK directory and JRE outside the JDK directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\jre` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6`. Which JRE i use for `keytool -import ...` command ?

Comment: @Basit Please use your browser and the development tools included in this to look at the exact data send during the post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem :). The problem was i was not setting the content type

```
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml"); //added

if ("POST".equals(method)) {   

    // set request method to POST
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

} else {

    // set request method to GET
    connection.setDoOutput(false);

}
```

After adding content type, i start getting response from the server.